# Alter MySQL table column to match id's from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Consider the following two MySQL tables:

```
companies
-----------------------
id ticker
1  AA
2  AAPL
3  ABT
4  AEP

tweets
-----------------------
tweet_id query (etc...)
1        $AA
2        $AA
3        $AAPL
4        $ABT
5        $AA
6        $AEP
7        $AEP
```

The table "companies" contains over 700 ticker symbols for various stocks. The table "tweets" contains millions of tweets. These tweets were gathered by querying Twitter.com for each ticker, prepended by "$", as this is the convention on Twitter when talking about a certain stock. I now would like to normalize the tweets table, as follows:

```
tweets
-----------------------
tweet_id query (etc...)
1        1
2        1
3        2
4        3
5        1
6        4
7        4
```

So now, the tweet with tweet_id one was obtained by querying for ticker with id 1, being AA (the "$" is not necessary to store in the database anymore). Now my question would be: is there a way to update the query-column in the tweets-table with one sql-query? Your help would be greatly appreciated, since I see a lot of work ahead (by using PHP, perhaps) if this is not possible :)

Comment: @a'r has got the answer.  Your schema might need a little rework, however, as you appear to want to store an integer-ish foreign key (`companies.id`) in a string-ish column (`tweets.query`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an update join. Something like this:

```
UPDATE tweets t
    JOIN companies c ON t.query = CONCAT('$', c.ticker)
SET t.query = c.id;
```